# Unpivot data with dynamic Date columns

Tags: pandas, apache-spark-sql, palantir-foundry

I need to unpivot a dataset with the column names in date format. To un-pivot, I would need to call column names, but they would keep changing every month; hence, I cannot use column names because of their dynamic nature.
Here is an example of the table:

[image]

I need to un-pivot these date columns and I cannot call column names as these columns may change next month. Here is the desired output:

[image]

Could you please help me with any solution for this in spark SQL or Pandas as I am using Palantir foundry.

Note:

1. There are hundreds of rows in data, this only one row is a sample example.
2. If I rename column names, changing them back to date columns would be difficult as well.

Thanks.

Comment: are the first 3 columns fixed? presumably all new columns (new dates) will be added to the right?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Why tag both [[tag:tsql]] and [[tag:apache-spark-sql]] here? What do this have to do with [[tag:pandas]] and [[tag:palantir-foundry]]?

Comment: I have removed the tag, added by mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) to achieve this

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars=df.columns[:3], value_vars=df.columns[3:], 
var_name='Date', value_name='Value')
```

Comment: Thank you Sanidhya. Worked like a charm. Appreciate your help.